# uart_write displays wrong value

Tags: uart

I'm creating a project using pic16f877a. I'm experiencing a problem when writing on `uart`. I'm new to `uart`.
Here is my code.

```
int x;
int x1;
char y[3];
char y1[3];
void main() {
UART1_Init(9600);
delay_ms(100);
TRISE = 0;

       TRISC = 0xff;
      // UART1_Write_Text("Length:");
      UART1_Write_Text("Length:");
       delay_ms(100);
       x=20;
       IntToStr(x,y);
       PORTE = 0b000;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){        // For senors 1-4
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){        //For sensors 5-8
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b010;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b100;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b110;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x++;}
       IntToStr(x,y);
       delay_ms(200);
       UART1_WRITE_TEXT(y);
       UART1_Write(13);

       delay_ms(500);
       UART1_Write_Text("Width:");
       delay_ms(100);
       x1=10;
       IntToStr(x1,y1);
       PORTE = 0b000;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){        // For senors 1-4
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){        //For sensors 5-8
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b010;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b100;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       PORTE = 0b110;
       if(PORTC.f0==1){
       x1++;}
       delay_ms(200);
       if(PORTC.f1==1){
       x1++;}
       IntToStr(x1,y1);
       delay_ms(200);
       UART1_WRITE_TEXT(y1);



}
```

Here is the output:

Length:26
Width:    166•

The value of y=26 it is correct, but when y1=16 is displayed it shows a wrong answer - the width should be 16.

Comment: Does your problem caused by code?   PORTC.f1 and PORTC.f0 may be came from outside (from the input pins of pic processor), how to understand it behaviour??

Comment: i guess it is cause by code because i did the same with variable x,y and x1,y1 but x, x1 displays the write string.